# iOS13 UIDocumentPickerViewController - open directory does not display select/open/cancel buttons

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, ios13, uidocumentpickerviewcontroller

I am using UIDocumentPickerViewController to browse through and let the user select a directory but on iOS 13 when this UIDocumentPickerViewController is displayed, the buttons that should be displayed like select/cancel and open/done are not displayed but when you tap on that location it does behaves like how it would if the buttons were visible. Also this problem is seen only on iOS 13. With the same code, the buttons are displayed on iOS 12. Any help is appreciated

I do have the navigation bar's tint color set to nil for an instance of UIDocumentBrowserViewController in AppDelegate didFinishLaunchingWithOptions.

```
if #available(iOS 11.0, *) {
    UINavigationBar.appearance(whenContainedInInstancesOf: [UIDocumentBrowserViewController.self]).tintColor = nil
} 


//Here is how UIDocumentPickerViewController is created and presented
let documentPickerViewController = UIDocumentPickerViewController(documentTypes:["public.folder"], in: .open)
...
...
...

self!.documentPickerViewController.delegate = self!
self!.documentPickerViewController.allowsMultipleSelection = true
self!.documentPickerViewController.modalPresentationStyle = .fullScreen     

self!.navigationController?.present(self!.documentPickerViewController, animated: true, completion:nil)
```

Here is a screenshot
[image]

Edit :
Here is the View Hierarchy - Not sure why DOCExportModeViewController on iOS 13. On iOS 12, it is a UIDocumentBrowserViewController for the same code. Any ideas how this can be fixed?

[image]

Comment: I observe this behavior in light mode, where buttons seem to be there but white on white, and therefore invisible. That's why they still work by knowing their position.

Answer (score 1):

I found this quick fix, if the document ViewController or any other picker is used at multiple places:

```
if #available(iOS 11.0, *) {
    UINavigationBar.appearance(whenContainedInInstancesOf: [UIDocumentBrowserViewController.self]).tintColor = nil
}
```

If you are worried for one place or have different colors at different places you can set tint color in `ViewWillAppear` and reset it in `ViewWillDisappear` method.

Answer (score 0):

I have observed that `UIDocumentPickerController` is a subclass of `UIViewController` Where `UIImagepickerController` is a subclass of `UINavigationController`.

if you try to set `tintColor` of `navBar` for UIImagePickerController , you can directly access it like `imagePicker.navigationBar.tintColor = .red`, coming to the document picker, you Cann't access `navigationBar` directly.you can access it by `imagePicker.navigationController?.navigationBar.tintColor = .red`. Here `navigationController is Optional`.thats why we are unable to access navbar directly and make changes.

> Apple created an app with document picker. Refer source code here: [Particles](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/view_controllers/building_an_app_based_on_the_document_browser_view_controller)

Comment: Your first suggestion does not work and I cannot set the tint color globally.

Comment: I have updated the answer and please make me correct if I was wrong.